# Android VideoView with duration -1

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am creating by myself a controller for a `VideoView` (I know it's easier to use a `Controller`, but it's a school homework), so the app appearance is the following (a `VideoView` with a `SeekBar` and 3 `Buttons`)

[image]

In the `onCreate` method I've written this code

```
VideoView vwVideo = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
vwVideo.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.baby);

SeekBar skbPosition = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarVideo);
skbPosition.setMax(vwVideo.getDuration());
```

but `getDuration()` returns -1, maybe because the video hasn't been loaded yet (*.mp4, 4.47 MB, 00:01:44), so I decided to set the maximum value of the `SeekBar` when the button "Play" is clicked but I don't know if this is the best way to solve the problem.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the duration of the video you can do this by using MediaMetadataRetriever.

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
//use setDataSource() functions to set your data source
retriever.setDataSource(context, Uri.fromFile(videoFile));
String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
long timeInMillisec = Long.parseLong(time);
```

Update me if any problem.